# Can a village or city be considered a landform?

Tags: word-usage, usage

I read a sentenence in a Wisegeek newsletter which was:

> The reforestation work is expected to create employment
>   opportunities, provide carbon offsets, and ensure storm barriers for the
>   villages that dot Myanmar's landscape.

Landscape means topographical features of a region such as hills, plains, etc. But can a village be pertinent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A landscape is not a 'landform'. 'Landscape' in the sense that you clearly mean, has the meaning 'a large area of countryside, especially in relation to its appearance'. Cambridge Dictionary even gives an example of man-made items 'dotting' a landscape:

> The landscape is dotted with the tents of campers and hikers.

Also, a man made feature such as a building can 'dominate' a landscape:

> The cathedral dominates the landscape for miles around.

[Landscape (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/landscape)

Comment: one thing I want to ask is can that _large area_ ,as you said in your answer, be so large that it can refer to a whole country(Myanmar)?

Comment: The 'large area' can refer to the whole country, although (usually) we cannot see a whole country all at once. Wherever you go in rural Myanmar, the writer implies, the landscape that you see is likely to be dotted with villages.

Answer (score 1):

A landform, (not a landscape) is a natural geological feature, such as a mountain or a valley. A village is not a landform, but a village might be part of a landscape.

Wikipedia has a comprehensive [list of landforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_landforms)

Comment: I took at list at the Wikipedia link; it might be worth pointing out to our learners that, although many of those terms are commonly-used, a few of them are rare and seldom-heard. There were a few in that list I'd never seen before. That's a great link, though.